# Null X Zero issue

Tags: php, mysql, null

Ok, this is driving me crazy!!
Got a MySQL table with an integer field default set to null.
Need to update it through a form submission. If form field is blank, set database field to NULL, ELSE set database field to form submission value.

So, in PHP I have: (staging code, still needs to be sanitized)

```
if($_POST['vendor-product'] != ''){
    $ms2VendorID = $_POST['vendor-product'];
}else{
    $ms2VendorID = '';
}
```

The problem is that instead of NULL it enters a zero. I've tried several different ways and nothing seems to be working.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you use a PDO or mysqli prepared statement, you should be able to pass the PHP value `null` as the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you assign `NULL` (as a string) to your variable in the else statement?

```
if($_POST['vendor-product'] != ''){
    $ms2VendorID = $_POST['vendor-product'];
}else{
    $ms2VendorID = "NULL";
}
```

Also, make sure that the field has not the `NOT NULL` constraint enabled.

Comment: Have tried it. Doesn't work. Still get a zero in the database

Comment: @Lorenzo99 did you check if the field is `NOT NULL`?

Comment: just checked and not null IS NOT checked. Default value for the field is NULL

Comment: Just edited the answer, you have to pass NULL as a string.

Comment: .. Got it. Also had to remove quotes from around the field. But your solution worked. Thanks a bunch!!